# Does there exist a rectifiable curve with infinite indefinite integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, differential-geometry, arc-length

Since $\gamma\in C^1$ implies that $\gamma$ is rectifiable and that $\int_{a}^{b}\left|\gamma'(t)\right|dt=\Lambda(\gamma)<\infty$, I was wondering if there would be any counterexample in a more general setting, e.g. $\gamma'\in\mathcal{R}$.
In addition, I saw a lot of solutions claiming that the divergence of the indefinite integral $\int_{a}^{b}\left|\gamma'(t)\right|dt$ simply implies that $\gamma$ is not rectifiable. This didnt't make much sense to me as the equation $\int_{a}^{b}\left|\gamma'(t)\right|dt=\Lambda(\gamma)$ holds only if $\gamma'\in C^1 \left(\Rightarrow \gamma'\in\mathcal{R}\left[a,b\right]\right)$, which is not the case.

More explicitly, would there exist a curve $\gamma:\left[a,b\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ which satisfies the following conditions?

1. $\gamma$ is differentiable and $\gamma'$ is Riemann integrable on all $\left[a,c\right]$ with $c<b$.
2. $\gamma$ is rectifiable.
3. $\int_{a}^{b}\left|\gamma'(t)\right|dt=\lim_{c\to b}\int_{a}^{c}\left|\gamma'(t)\right|dt=\infty$.

Comment: I apologize for badly phrasing my question. I am new to this community and was not aware of the required standards. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer.**

No there is no such $\gamma$ satisfying those 3 conditions.

---

**Long Answer.**

Usually, theorems are true in much more general circumstances than you may have been exposed to, and that is indeed the case here. For example, the following statement is true:

> **Theorem 1.**
>
> If $\gamma:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}^n$ is differentiable at every point of $[a,b]$, and $\gamma'$ is Riemann-integrable on $[a,b]$, then $\gamma$ is rectifiable and
> \begin{align}
> L(\gamma)=\int_a^b|\gamma'(t)|\,dt
> \end{align}

Here, we're working with a proper Riemann-integral on the RHS. Even though the statement involves only Riemann integrals, I do not know how to prove this without more machinery involving absolute continuity/Lebesgue integrals, and especially the Lebesgue version of the FTC. In the above theorem, proving rectifiability of $\gamma$ and the inequality $\leq$ are elementary. The tough part is proving the inequality $\geq$.

Let me just mention how the proof goes. First, define the total variation function $\Gamma:[a,b]\to[0,\infty]$ as
\begin{align}
\Gamma(x):=L(\gamma|_{[a,x]}).
\end{align}
Now, let $\{t_0,\dots, t_N\}$ be an arbitrary partition of $[a,x]$; then
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^N|\gamma(t_{i})-\gamma(t_{i-1})|&=\sum_{i=1}^N\left|\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}\gamma'(t)\,dt\right|\tag{FTC}\\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^N\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}|\gamma'(t)|\,dt\\
&=\int_a^x|\gamma'(t)|\,dt
\end{align}
Thus, by taking the supremum over all the partitions, we have that $\Gamma(x):=L(\gamma|_{[a,x]})\leq \int_a^x|\gamma'(t)|\,dt$. In particular, this is true for $x=b$, thus it proves the rectifiability of $\gamma$ and the inequality $\leq$ mentioned in the theorem (in particular, it also shows $\Gamma$ is real-valued; i.e doesn't take the value $\infty$).

To prove the reverse inequality, let us temporarily make the extra hypothesis that $\Gamma$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $\Gamma'$ is Riemann-integrable on $[a,b]$. Then, for any $t\in (a,b)$ and sufficiently small $h>0$, we have by the additivity of lengths of paths that
\begin{align}
|\gamma(t+h)-\gamma(t)|&\leq L(\gamma|_{[t,t+h]})\\
&=L(\gamma|_{[a,t+h]})-L(\gamma|_{[a,t]})\\
&=\Gamma(t+h)-\Gamma(t)
\end{align}
Dividing by $h$ and taking the limit as $h\to 0^+$ shows that $|\gamma'(t)|\leq \Gamma'(t)$. Integrating from $a$ to $x$ and using the FTC (the baby Riemann version) shows that
\begin{align}
\int_a^x|\gamma'(t)|\,dt&\leq \int_a^x\Gamma'(t)\,dt=\Gamma(x)-\Gamma(a)=\Gamma(x),
\end{align}
since $\Gamma(a)=0$.

This proves the theorem under the extra hypothesis of $\Gamma$ being differentiable with Riemann-integrable derivative. It turns out that this is unnecessary, but actually proving the theorem without these assumptions is much harder and I do not know how to do it without Lebesgue integrals and the notion of absolute continuity, and the corresponding Lebesgue-integral version of the Fundamental theorem of calculus.

For completeness, here's how the proof goes. We only have to assume $\gamma:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}^n$ is [absolutely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Definition) (for short, $\gamma$ is AC). Note also that Wikipedia only defines absolute continuity for functions with $\Bbb{R}$ as the target space, but the same definition can be made for $\Bbb{R}^n$-valued functions. From here, it is not too hard to show that $\Gamma$ is also AC. Hence (see theorem 7.20 in Rudin's RCA, which again holds for $\Bbb{R}^n$-valued functions by slight modifications), both $\gamma$ and $\Gamma$ are differentiable a.e on $[a,b]$ and the FTC holds. At any point $t\in (a,b)$ where $\gamma$ and $\Gamma$ are differentiable, we prove as above that $|\gamma'(t)|\leq \Gamma'(t)$. Since this is true for a.e $t\in [a,b]$, the Lebesgue-version of the FTC now implies
\begin{align}
\int_a^x|\gamma'(t)|\,dt&\leq \int_a^x\Gamma'(t)\,dt=\Gamma(x)-\Gamma(a)=\Gamma(x),
\end{align}
since $\Gamma(a)=0$.

So, the proof idea is actually very simple, but getting the technical details right under the weak assumptions is the difficult part.

---

To summarize, one has the following strong theorem:

> **Theorem 2.**
>
> If $\gamma:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}^n$ is AC, then $\gamma$ is rectifiable and
> \begin{align}
> L(\gamma)&=\int_a^b|\gamma'(t)|\,dt
> \end{align}
> (using a Lebesgue integral on the RHS).

Theorem 1 is a special case of theorem 2 (since the hypotheses of theorem 1 imply those of theorem 2; see Rudin's RCA theorem 7.20 for this, and also because if the Riemann integral exists, so does the Lebesgue integral, and the two are equal).

In view of theorem 1 (the proof of which we had to take a long detour), it follows that there is no curve $\gamma$ satisfying the three conditions you pose.