# The length of a curve that has Riemann integrable derivative [Mathematical anaylsis]

Tags: analysis, definite-integrals, curves

- Let $-∞<a<b<+∞$ and $k∈ℕ$. If a function $γ:[a,b]→ℝ^k$ has bounded derivative on $[a,b]$,

  (a) prove that $\gamma$ is rectifiable.

  (b) If $\gamma'$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, determine whether the equality $Λ(γ)=\int_a^b|γ'(t)|dt$ is valid or not.

I have already proved the problem (a), just using a theorem "$∃c∈(a,b), |f(b)-f(a)| ≤ (b-a)|f'(c)|$" where $f:[a,b]→ℝ^k$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. And I also know if $γ'$ is cont on $[a,b]$, then $Λ(γ) = \int_a^b|γ'(t)|dt$. But, what about the case that $γ'∈$ on $[a,b]$? Are two values $Λ(γ)$ and $\int_a^b|γ'(t)|dt$ same each other?

Reference: Principles of Mathematical Analysis - 3rd Edition by Walter Rudin, 137p

Comment: Please use [LaTeX](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) to typeset your mathematics, and you will be more likely to get help.

Comment: You might try to see if your proof for the case when $\gamma'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$  can be modified to work when $\gamma'$ is continuous a.e. on $[a,b]$ and bounded, since Lebesgue-Vitali theorem says for bounded functions that's equivalent to Riemann integrability on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Yes it’s true, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4230730/568204) is a proof.  Unfortunately it is not elementary; I use several results from chapter 7 of Rudin’s RCA.